# Why Progress bar don't stop at my value placed in the input box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
var i = 0;

var My_Button = document.getElementById("btn1")

var Numerica = parseInt(My_Button.value)


function update() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");
  var width = 1;
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 10);
  function scene() {
    if (width >= Numerica) {
      clearInterval(identity);
    } else {
      width++;
      element.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#Progress_Status {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar {
  width: 2%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3>
    
<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px" type = text id = "btn1" name = "btn10" > <span id ="option1" style="font-size:30px">Option1</span>

<p>Pogress Bar</p>

<div id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>
```

I want to decide a number inside the Input box and make to that the bar progress until that decided number.
Why is the previously showed code the bar never stop?
I am transforming right the value into an integer

Comment: `parseInt(My_Button)` won't hold the desired value, did you mean `parseInt(My_Button.value)` ? Also, you should get the value after the button is pressed.

Comment: @Ostone5 is not working anyway

Comment: Did you read the second part of the comment? You're setting `Numerica` when the page first loads, not after the user fills in the input.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to take value from an input element, you need to take `.value` of your `getElementById()`.

Second, you tried taking the value before you actually inserted any value, basically on page load.

### Conclusion:

I've moved those lines of code inside your `update()` function, and added `.value` on your `My_Button` variable. That's all that's changed.

```
var My_Button = document.getElementById("btn1").value;
var Numerica = Number(My_Button)
```

```js
var i = 0;

function update() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");
  var width = 1;
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 10);
  var My_Button = document.getElementById("btn1").value;
  var Numerica = Number(My_Button)
console.log(Numerica);
  function scene() {
    if (width >= Numerica) {
      clearInterval(identity);
    } else {
      width++;
      element.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#Progress_Status {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar {
  width: 2%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3>

<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px" type = text id = "btn1" name = "btn10" > <span id ="option1" style="font-size:30px">Option1</span>

<p>Pogress Bar</p>

<div id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>

<script src ="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use interval in your case. You can achieve it with `transition` in CSS.

*Side note if you want to get a value from an input field, you need to call `.value`. In your case, it is `document.getElementById("btn1").value`.*

```js
var i = 0;

var My_Button = document.getElementById("btn1");

function update() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");
  var width = My_Button.value || 1; //need to get value every time
  element.style.width = width + '%';
}
```

```css
#Progress_Status {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width .2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3>

<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px" type = text id="btn1" name = "btn10" > <span id ="option1" style="font-size:30px">Option1</span>

<p>Pogress Bar</p>

<div id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>

</body>
</html>
```

---

If you still want to use interval, you need to call `clearInterval` every time when you trigger `update()` like below

```js
var i = 0;

var My_Button = document.getElementById("btn1")

var identity; //move the declaration here
function update() {
  var Numerica = parseInt(My_Button.value) //need to get value every time
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");
  var width = 1;
  //var identity = setInterval(scene, 10); //remove this
  if(identity) {
     clearInterval(identity) //clear the interval if you click Start Download again
  }
  identity = setInterval(scene, 10);
  function scene() {
    if (width >= Numerica) {
      clearInterval(identity);
    } else {
      width++;
      element.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#Progress_Status {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3>

<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px" type = text id="btn1" name = "btn10" > <span id ="option1" style="font-size:30px">Option1</span>

<p>Pogress Bar</p>

<div id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>

</body>
</html>
```